# apostrophe cms loading from database

Tags: apostrophe-cms

My main question is how can I insert something into the database and then read that information in and pass it to the frontend? Step by step would be helpful considering I am new to apostrophe. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

These sort of high level-themes are covered in the Technical Overviews, namely [A 30,000 foot overview](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/technical-overviews/technical-overview.html#content-in-apostrophe-docs-pieces-pages-widgets-and-areas) and [How Apostrophe modules are structured](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/technical-overviews/how-apostrophe-modules-are-structured.html). I would recommend following the [Getting Started tutorial](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/index.html) and then posting specific questions you have once you have a project stood up.